# Significance of the Mazur-Ulam Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

The Mazur-Ulam theoem states that any surjective isometry between any two real normed spaces is necessarily affine.

What is the significance of the theorem? It is said that the birth of the Banach space theory is due to this theorem[[1](https://lmb.univ-fcomte.fr/IMG/pdf/coursLens2010.pdf)], but I don't see why.

Comment: In what possible way is this recreational mathematics?

Comment: So you know what Banach space theory deals with?